# Relation between points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ and $\partial \mathbb{H}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I have proved that $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ has a fixed point in $\mathbb{D}$ iff its correspondent from $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ has a fixed point in $\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is open unit disk, and $\mathbb{H}$ is upper half-plane.

But I don't know how to show that $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ has a fixed point in $\partial \mathbb{D}$ iff its corespondent from $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ has a fixed point in $\partial \mathbb{H} \cup \{\infty\}$. I don't even know if it's true. There exists some sort of theorem that say that a homeomorphic functions preserve the number of fixed points or something? Because there is a homeomorphism between $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{H}} \cup \{\infty\}$. Thanks!

$\textbf{EDIT!}$
Ok. So what I know is that $F:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}, F(z) = \frac{i-z}{i+z}$ is a biholomorphism. I need to show that this extends to a homeomorphism $F : \overline{\mathbb{H}} \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We have that $\lim_{z \to x}F(z) = \frac{i-x}{i+x} = F(x)$ so it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, we have that $\lim_{z \to \infty}F(z) = F(\infty)$ so $F$ is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$. Same thing for $F^{-1}$, so $F$ is a homeomorphism from $\overline{H}$ to $\overline{D}$.

Next, $f \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ iff $f(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{\alpha-z}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. So, if $\alpha = 1 \implies f(z) = e^{i \theta}$ which is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, and if $\alpha \ne 1$ we have that  if $w \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$, then $\lim_{z \to w} f(z) = f(w)$. So $f$ also extends to a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$.

Then, we know that the function $\Lambda : \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D}) \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H}), \Lambda(\phi) = F^{-1} \circ \phi \circ F$ is an isomorphism, and $p$ is fixed point for $\phi$ iff $F^{-1}(p)$ is fixed point for $\Lambda(\phi)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{D}$. But by the facts proved above, we can use this for $p \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ also.

$\textbf{EDIT 2:}$ (replaced the last paragraph with this below)

So... we know that $\Lambda:\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D}) \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H}), \Lambda(\phi) = F^{-1} \circ \phi \circ F$ is an isomorphism of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ (as groups).

Also, each of the functions $F, F^{-1}$, and $\phi$ can be extended to a homeomorphism on closure of its domain in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$, so the functions are well defined on the closure of their domains.

Also, by the fact that composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, and image of boundary of domain through a homeomorphism is the boundary of codomain, we can conclude that $p \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ is fixed point for $\phi$ iff $F^{-1}(p)$ is fixed point for $\Lambda(\phi)$.

Comment: You should include the point at infinity in $\partial {\mathbb H}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry for confusion. By $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ I wanted to say that it includes $\infty$ but I've modified now to be clear

Comment: Then the key is that the conformal (Moebius) isomorphism $f$ of $D$ and $H$ extends to an isomorphism of their closures in the Riemann sphere. Now, think of the relation between the fixed points of $\phi$ and its conjugate $f\phi f^{-1}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I used this to prove for $D$ and $H$ but i don't understand how it extends to an isomorhpism on their closures.

Comment: Hmm: Is your problem that you do not know  why each Moebius transformation is a self-homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere? I am not quite getting where your difficulty is coming from.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I've added something to edit in my post. Can you check if it's ok what I've understood? Thanks!

Comment: It is a bit muddled. If I were you I would just check that **all** linear fractional transformations (with complex coefficients) define homeomorphisms of the Riemann sphere. This way you do not have to check it for several different types. The last paragraph also misses the point since you need to work with the closures in the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ok. I understand that all linear fractional transformations define homeomorphisms of the Riemann sphere now. But in the last paragraph how I need to work with the closures in the Riemann sphere? Can you help me please?

Comment: I've added another edit, more detailed. I want to know what I need to edit to be a good proof... Thanks!

Comment: I still do not know if your textbook or lectures already proved that every linear-fractional transformation defines a homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere. If they did, there is no need for any of the limits written in the proof. If they did not, then what you wrote is not a proof of continuity but just a restatement of the definition in several special cases without any attempt on actually proving continuity.  Maybe your instructor finds such writing acceptable, I would not if you were in my class.

Comment: @MoisheKohan no, I've not already proved that every linear-fractional transformation defines a homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere. Can you make a correct proof (for my question, using that every linear fractioanl transformation defines ahomeomorphism of the Riemann sphere) for me to see how I need to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: OK, I will add an answer later on (will try not to forget!).

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks!

Comment: This is not a general topology question, as you specifically use conformal maps, etc, not general continuous maps.  I'll remove the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a, b, c, d$ are complex numbers satisfying $ad-bc\ne 0$. Then one defines the *linear-fractional transformation* $\gamma$ of the Riemann sphere $S^2= {\mathbb C}\cup \{\infty\}$ by the formula:
$$
\gamma(z)= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, z\in {\mathbb C}\setminus \{-d/c\},
$$
$$
\gamma(-d/c)=\infty,$$
$$
 \gamma(\infty)= \frac{a}{c},
$$
unless $c=0$ in which case $\gamma(\infty)=\infty$.

The next lemma and its corollary are routine calculations, I will give only partial proofs, leaving the rest to you:

Lemma. 1. Every linear-fractional transformation of the Riemann sphere is continuous.

2. Every linear-fractional transformation of the Riemann sphere is  invertible and its inverse is again a linear-fractional transformation.
3. The composition of any pair of linear-fractional transformations is again a linear-fractional transformation.

Proof. 1. Continuity of $\gamma$ at points $\ne \infty$ and $\ne -d/c$ is a direct consequence of the limit laws in complex analysis.
$$
\lim_{z\to \infty} \gamma(z)=  \lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=  \lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{a+\frac{b}{z}}{c+\frac{d}{z}}= \frac{a}{c}=\gamma(\infty), 
$$
In order to compute
$$
\lim_{z\to -d/c} \gamma(z)=  \lim_{z\to - d/c} \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
for $c\ne 0$ I will consider first
$$
\lim_{z\to -d/c}  \frac{cz+d}{az+b} =  \frac{c \frac{-d}{c}+d}{a \frac{-d}{c}+b} =0,
$$
where we use the assumption that $ad-bc\ne 0$. Thus,
$$
\lim_{z\to -d/c} \gamma(z)=\infty=\gamma(-d/c).$$

I leave the case $c=0$ for you to check, as well as claims 2 and 3. qed

Corollary 1. (i) Every linear-fractional transformation is a homeomorphism. (ii) The set of linear-fractional transformations is a group with respect to the operation of composition.

Proof. The first claim is a consequence of Lemma, parts 1 and 2. The second claim is a consequence of Lemma, parts 2 and 3. qed

For a linear-fractional transformation $\gamma$ preserving a subset $E\subset S^2$, let $F(\gamma, E)$ denote the set of fixed points of
$\gamma$ in $E$.

Corollary 2. Suppose that $\alpha, \beta$ are linear-fractional transformations and $E\subset S^2$ is such that $\beta(E)=E$. Then
$$
F(\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}, \alpha(E))= \alpha(F(\beta, E)). 
$$
Proof. A direct verification, valid for bijections of sets in general. qed

For a subset $E\subset S^2$ let $\partial E$ denote the boundary of $E$ in $S^2$. (I assume that you already took a topology class and know what this means. Let me know if you do not.)

Corollary 3. Suppose that $D\subset S^2$ is a subset and $\alpha, \beta$  are linear-fractional transformation such that $\beta(D)=D$.
Then
$$
F(\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}, \partial \alpha(D))= \alpha(F(\beta, \partial D)). 
$$
Proof. Since $\alpha$ is a homeomorphism of $S^2$, for every subset $D\subset S^2$ we have $\alpha(\partial D)= \partial \alpha(D)$ (this is a general property of homeomorphisms of topological spaces). For the same reason,
$\beta(\partial D)= \partial \beta(D)= \partial D$.  Now, set $E:= \partial D$. Corollary 2 implies that
$$
F(\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}, \partial \alpha(D))= \alpha(F(\beta, \partial D)). 
$$
qed

Corollary 4. Suppose that $D\subset {\mathbb C}$ is the open unit disk, $\beta$ is a linear-fractional transformation preserving $D$ (i.e. $\beta(D)=D$). Let $\alpha$ be a linear-fractional transformation mapping $D$ onto the upper half-plane $U$. Then $\beta: \partial D\to \partial D$ has nonempty fixed-point set if and only if $\gamma= \alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}$ has nonempty fixed-point set in $\partial U$.

Proof. By Corollary 3,
$$
F(\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}, \partial \alpha(D))= \alpha(F(\beta, \partial D)), 
$$
i.e.
$$
F(\gamma, \partial U)= \alpha(F(\beta, \partial D)), 
$$
Since the right-hand side is nonempty, the left-hand side is also nonempty. qed

Comment: Corollary 4 shows also that the number of fixed points of $\beta$ in $\partial D$ is the same as the number of fixed points of $\gamma$ in $\partial U$, isn't it?

Comment: @MathLearner: of course...